FMTONLY and sp_describe_first_result_set dont work with stored procedures that have different select columns depending on the parameters
All our report queries rely on FMTONLY to pull the column names as part of the coding of our legacy system. I have some stored procedures that return different columns, depending on the parameters passed.
Example:
If LEN(@StartMonth) > 0
BEGIN
    SELECT One, Two, Three 
    FROM XYZ
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT One, Two 
    FROM XYZ
END

FMTONLY returns 2 sets of result (One, Two, Three and One, Two)
If I try sp_describe_first_result_set, it always returns 1 result,  One, Two, Three without considering the 2nd Select statement.
It looks like they both evaluate without actually running the query. Does anyone have an alternate way that I could return the column names based on the parameters sent to the stored procedure?
Preferably without the overhead of running the query to get the columns and running it a second time to get the results.

This may help (https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/if-10-begin-set-fmtonly-off-end). By setting FMTONLY  on and off at different points in the SP you can allow only the minimal amount of code to be executed to return column list.
